# How to create a large number of tables

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I've got a large dataset to work with to create a storage system to monitor movement in a store. There's over like 300 products in that store and the main structure of all tables is the same. The only difference is the data inside. There's a larger data base called StorageTF and I want to create a lot of tables called Product_1,Product_2,Product_3 etc..
The table structure should look like

The main large data set (table) looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE StoringTF (
Store_code INTEGER,
Store TEXT,
Product_Date TEXT,
Permission INTEGER,
Product_Code INTEGER,
Product_Name TEXT,
Incoming INTEGER,
Unit_Buying_Price INTEGER,
Total_Buying_Price INTEGER,
Outgoing INTEGER,
Unit_Sell_Price INTEGER,
Total_Sell_Price INTEGER,
Description TEXT)
```

I want the user to input a code in an entry called PCode 
it looks like this

```
PCode = Entry(root, width=40)
PCode.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

then a function compares the input with all codes in the main table and takes that one and gets the table that has the same product_code.
So the sequence is. All the product tables for all product_Codes in the main table will be created and will have all data from main table that has same product_code.
Then when the program is opened the user inputs a product_code
the program picks the table that has the same code and shows it to the user.
Thanks a lot and I know it's hard but I really need your help and I'm certain you can help me. Thanks.

The product table should look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE Product_x (Product_Code INTEGER, 
    Product_Name TEXT, --taken from main table from lines that has same product code
    Entry_Date, TEXT,
    Permission_Number INTEGER,
    Incoming INTEGER,
    Outgoing INTEGER,
    Description TEXT,
    Total_Quantity_In_Store INTEGER, --which is main table's incoming - outgoing
    Total_Value_In_Store INTEGER --main table's total_buying_price - total_sell_price
    )
```

Thank you for your help and hope you can figure it out because I'm really struggling with it.

Comment: You want one table per product? Don't do that. One table for all of them is a better approach.

Comment: You say "The only difference is the data inside", but do you mean only the data values, or that the data schema is different?  Do ALL the product tables have the same schema as Product_x table you show?  If so, then the table already has a Product_Code.  That means you have a **single** table and simply enter multiple rows with a unique Product_Code for each product.  Not only is one table a better approach, but it is the only approach that will let you take full advantage of SQL features and foreign-key relationships, etc.

Comment: You should research **data normalization**.  That is the key principle for designing relational databases.  For instance, you should avoid duplicate data columns like `Product_Name`.  That column should only be in the `StoringTF`.  Calculated columns are also usually redundant and unnecessary--don't store the `Total_Value_In_Store` column, rather calculate it when needed by query and/or view.   Having duplicate columns invites mismatched data or at least unnecessary care to make sure all columns are synced when one is updated.  Instead you can just query joined tables to get related values.

Comment: The difference is the data values and the schema is consistent. I want a normal non programmer user to use that table. The main table already has them combined. I want a table that shows movement of each product. I think I'd select some columns from main table but I don't know how I'd update the only some columns with select columns from main table where product code = PCode.get() "which is the entry box".  is that possible. If it is it will reduce a lot of work. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> I think I'd select some columns from main table but I don't know how I'd update the only some columns with select columns from main table where product code = PCode.get() "which is the entry box". is that possible.

Yes, it is definitely possible to present only certain rows and columns of data to the user.

However, there are many patterns (i.e. programming techniques) that you could follow for presenting data to the user, but every common, best-practice technique always separates the backend data (i.e. database) from the user interface.  It is not necessary to limit presentation of data to one entire table at a time.  In most cases the data should never be presented and/or exposed to the user exactly as it appears in a table.  Of course sometimes the data is simple and direct enough to do that, but most applications re-format and group data in *different* **views** for proper presentation.  (Here the term *view* is meant as a very general, abstract term for representing data in alternative ways from how it is stored.  I mention specific sqlite views below.)

The entire philosophy behind modern databases is for efficient, well-designed storage that can be **queried** to return just what data is appropriate for each application.  Much of this capability is based on the host-language data models, but sqlite directly supports features to help with this.  For instance, a *view* can be defined to select only certain columns and rows at a time (i.e. choose certain Produce_Code values).  An *sqlite view* is just an SQL query that is saved and can have certain properties and actions defined for it.  By default, a [sqlite view](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) is read-only, but triggers can be defined to allow updates to the underlying tables via the view.

*From my earlier comment*:  You should research **data normalization**. That is the key principle for designing relational databases. For instance, you should avoid duplicate data columns like `Product_Name`. That column should only be in the StoringTF. Calculated columns are also usually redundant and unnecessary--don't store the `Total_Value_In_Store` column, rather calculate it when needed by query and/or **view**. Having duplicate columns invites mismatched data or at least unnecessary care to make sure all columns are synced when one is updated.  Instead you can just query joined tables to get related values.

Honestly, these concepts can require much study before implementing properly.  By all means, go forward with developing a solution that fits your needs, but a Stack Overflow answer is no place for full tutorials which I perceive that you might need.  Really your question seems more about overall design and I think my answer can get you started on the right track.  Anything more specific and you'll need to ask other questions later on.

Comment: Ok, so a more specific question. How can I get the value of the Entry PCode.get() and assign it to be the where condition. For example: SELECT * FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = PCode.get(). Is it possible ?